# Visual basic Deserialize json url

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization

im trying to get imdb id through the id of the movie using visual basic using json deserialize

`dim rawresp as string = read.readtoend()
rawresp = textbox3.text`

its working fine but i dont want the whole json to write in the textbox i want only the imdb_id to write into my textbox3.text

lets say thats the link of the json ->https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=315b4646c080bc576529769498ccc658

```
Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
    Dim uristring As String = ("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + TextBox6.Text + "?api_key=315b4646c080bc576529769498ccc658")
    Dim uri As New Uri(uristring)
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
    request.Method = "get"
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim read = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)
    Dim rawresp As String = read.ReadToEnd()
    Dim dict As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of List(Of Object))(rawresp)
    For Each item As Object In dict
        TextBox3.Text = item("imdb_id").ToString()
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: yes its helpful asf thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Hope this will be helped

```
Dim jsonResulttodict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(rawresp)
Dim imdb_ID = jsonResulttodict.item ("imdb_id")
```

Comment: im wondering if you can help 
im making a loop somewhere in my progam at one point i`ll reach a 404 error in my http webrequest in the same place here 
   ` Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()`
i want that if i didnt find the url it makes a function and if it does it works normally

Comment: @Shashtie I'm not clear you properly, can u please post it as a question